# What is this python syntax trying to do?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm wondering what is actually trying to happen in the following line. Forgive me I'm new to python syntax, thanks for the help!

```
Handlers[type(dbw_msg)](dbw_msg)
```

Where 
handlers = secondary: self.secondary_manage.handle.message

and dbw_msg = py_from_can(can_msg)

where py_from can is defined as

```
def py_from_can(can_msg):
try:
    if can_msg.ID in py_can_types:
        return py_can_types[can_msg.ID].py_from_can(can_msg)
except NotImplementedError:
    pass
return None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, without any other context, all we can say is:

```
Handlers[type(dbw_msg)](dbw_msg)
```

`Handlers` gets *subscripted* (i.e. the square-brackets) with `type(db_msg)`. We can only assume this is some sort of mapping (a `dict`) where the keys are `type` objects.

Finally, the value that is returned by the subcription operation get's called, i.e. the `()` parens. So, `Handlers` is some mapping from `type` objects to a callable (e.g. functions).

So, for example:

```
>>> handlers = {int: lambda x: x**2, str: str.upper}    
>>> a = 8
>>> b = 'foo'
>>> handlers[type(a)](a)
64
>>> handlers[type(b)](b)
'FOO'
```

Note, `str.upper` is merely the `.upper` method from your normal strings, i.e.:

```
>>> "baz".upper() # note the call!
'BAZ'
```

Is the same as:

```
>>> str.upper("baz")
'BAZ'
```

And a `lambda` is merely a way to write anonymous functions. It is equivalent to:

```
def square(x):
    return x**2
```

Comment: Or `Handlers` is some kind of sequence and `type` returns an `int` and is indexing into it

Comment: @CoryKramer heh. Yes, that *is* possible. It **could** be anything that implements a `__getitem__` method.

Comment: This is very helpful, just to confirm I got the syntax. in the first line. handlers = {int: lambda x: x**2, str.upper} Im assume these are logical tests where if an int, multiple by 2, if a string, place to uppercase.

Comment: @Salty I'm not sure what you mean, this is *merely a dictionary*, i.e. a *mapping*, from types to callables. Essentially, it gives you the right function for the type you feed it.

Comment: @ChristianDean thanks for the edit. Didn't notice that!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Glad I could help out ;-)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Sorry I'm brand new to python. I think `__getitem__` is the right direciton. Opening up handlers i get `handlers = {dict}{<class__main__.vehicleInterface'>: bound method VehicleInterfaceFrame.handle_message of <__main__.VehicleInterfaceFrame instance at 0x00D6DE90>`.... with more main.vehicle parameters. – Salty 7 mins ago

Comment: @Salty sorry, I don't understand what that output is. Are you using type-hinting or a static-type checker, like `mypy` on this project? Anyway, don't worry about `__getitem__` for now, but basically, it is a hook that allows you to implement indexing for your types. So, you can think of `some_list = [1,2,3]`; then `some_list[0]` is equivalent to `some_list.__getitem__(0)`. But that's a bit more detail than you need to understand the above. It is merely a `dict`, i.e. a hashmap.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'm using PyCharm to debug. basically `dbw_msg` from above should be an array of values and im trying to figure out what is supposed to happen to them in the output `handlers[type(dbw_msg)](dbw_msg)` because this is currently a fail point in this code on older versions of python.

Comment: @Salty consider accepting this answer.  See here for [**WhatToDoWhenSomeoneAnswers**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)